# Laravel - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

This is the Login function of my project, the problem is that when I call this function the program gives me this error:

```
public function login()
{
    $username = Session::get("login");
    $password = app("request")->input("password");
    $logged = app("request")->input("logged");
    $response = response("200");
    $data = DB::table("utenti")->where("username",$username)->where("password",md5(sha1(md5(sha1($password)))))->count();
    if($data == 1)
    {
        if($logged == "true")
        {
            $lung_pass = 64;
            $mypass = "";
            for ($x=1; $x<=$lung_pass; $x++)
            {
                if ($x % 2){
                    $mypass.= chr(rand(97,122));
                }else{
                    $mypass = $mypass . rand(0,9);
                }
            }
            $response -> cookie(cookie()->forever("token",$mypass));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the jQuery script of the Login:

```
var password = $("#password").val();
        $.post("{{route("login")}}", {logged:$("#remember-me").prop("checked"), _token: "{{csrf_token()}}", password: password}, function (data) {
            if (data == "true") {
                $("#logged").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
            } else {
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#message").show(1000);
                $("#message").html("La Password è risultata Errata!");
            }
        });
        return false;
```

Route:

```
Route::post("/login", "Controller@login")->name("login");
```

Comment: 'P.S. The Route is a Post Route Thanks' Laravel thinks otherwise. Post your routes.

Comment: P.S. you should show us the routes anyway, it's not that we don't believe you, but just to make sure :) because generally it's the cause of this kind of errors

Comment: What you doing there?     
`$data = DB::table("utenti")->where("username",$username)->where("password",md5(sha1(md5(sha1($password)))));`

Comment: @Konafets quad hashing is the best hash LUL

Comment: as others mentioned this is to do with your routes. you are POSTing to a route which is most probably accepting the GET method.

Comment: You do know Laravel has a build in hashing algorithm?

Comment: Some remarks to your code:
`->where()` returns a Builder object, so it will unlikely become `1` if you found an records which matches. 

Laravel uses `bcrypt` to encrypt the users password. Unless you did not implement your own password hashing method – and I hope your did not – your code password hashing in `where()` makes no sense.

The whole code of `$myPass` generation is useless. Why returning `ld`? What happens if the user did not pass? Your JS code will return always `false`, since `post` is async

Comment: btw, do you have a form on that page .. is it possible the form is just submitting?

Comment: Is most cool an Ajax Login 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace following**

```
Route::post("/login", "Controller@login")->name("login");
```

**with**

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/login', [ 
    'uses'=>'Controller@login'
]);
```

And see if the problem is with route or not. Your error message(**MethodNotAllowedHttpException**) is related with the HTTP methods(GET, POST, PUT, OPTION etc) mismatch.

This is how you ignore **http method exception.**

This post is for your exception.